# How can I return a human readable time range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I used the code below to return a number, but it's not human readable. How do I convert it to a `x hours x mins x second` format?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Time.now.end_of_day() -Time.now
 => 31612.235963075
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a human readable time range using ruby on rails ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136248/how-to-generate-a-human-readable-time-range-using-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words)`(Time.now, Time.now.end_of_day)`