# How to show time written out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, date

With Rails, how do I write the time out, like this:

`2 days 12 hours 5 minutes and 14 seconds`

I feel like there's a Date helper that does it, but digging around the docs hasn't surfaced anything.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679266/can-ruby-print-out-time-difference-duration-readily

Comment: That's called a timespan. [Check this out.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html)

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274549/how-can-i-return-a-human-readable-time-range and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136248/how-to-generate-a-human-readable-time-range-using-ruby-on-rails/4136485#4136485 and...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[humantime](https://github.com/jfi/humantime) is one option, but Rails already has [time_ago_in_words](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words) and [distance_of_time_in_words](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words).

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime.strftime.  It works the same as the C strftime, so you can find documentation on the web.

```
DateTime.strftime("%j days %H hours %M minutes and %S seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words

If not you can be inspired by the source code of this helper