# Ruby: format number of seconds to formatted time

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Ruby print out time difference (duration) readily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679266/can-ruby-print-out-time-difference-duration-readily)

I have a length of time that is stored as a number of seconds. Is there a way to format it either into HH:MM format or to something human readable, such as '2 hours, 15 minutes'?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to probably adapt the code used in this rails function: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words