# Python timedelta and datetime.min in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

I have the following code in Python:

```
start_time = (datetime.min+ timedelta(hours=9)).strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

This gives the value '09:00 AM' and to add 30 minutes to the above I can do:

```
start_time + timedelta(minutes=30)
```

1. In Ruby what would be the equivalent of `timedelta(hours=9)`?
2. How can I create a `start_time` similar to the above Python code in Ruby?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679266/can-ruby-print-out-time-difference-duration-readily/1679963#1679963

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are supposed to write the code and when it doesn't work, ask how to fix the specific problem. As is, you want us to write the code for you, which is not how it works.

Comment: @The Tin Man: I dont want to sound rude but in this case if i knew how to write the ruby equivalent i wouldnt have asked this question. I knew the logic of what i wanted to accomplish and i shared that, all i wanted to know was the ruby syntax for the same as i was not able to figure it out myself. Anyways thanks for welcoming me to stack overflow ;)

Comment: While it'd seem appropriate to ask "how do I write this code in another language" questions on Stack Overflow, that's not what the site is for. Instead, you have to do the research, and try, and once you do that, if you fail, ask a specific question about your attempt. As is, your question is premature. I'm the one who told you why you're getting close votes, there are other users who silently voted the same way, so others feel the same way.

Comment: @The Tin Man: Thanks i get your point, but my ideas on how to do the same in ruby were not even close, so didnt want to post them. Also another main reason for not posting was i wanted to know an unbiased solution. Anyways, will post whatever i can from now onwards. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: I think this question is headed in the direction of [SO's documentation initiative](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow), and isn't unreasonable to answer in the meantime (obviously, since I did). All of the information is in the `Time` and `DateTime` documentation, but there's a lot of extraneous stuff to grok in there that someone with a little more experience can distill quickly to get the OP started. At this point in Ruby's life, the broad strokes are unlikely to change, so could be helpful to many future askers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple equivalent of Python's `datetime` would be Ruby's [`Time`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html).

The `Time` initializer accepts `year, month, day, hour, minute, second, offset`, so instantiating the earliest possible `Time` is `start_time = Time.new(0)`.

`Time` will perform addition in seconds, so you can add 9 hours with `start_time + (60 * 60 * 9)` or 30 minutes with `start_time + (60 * 30)`.

I'm not sure if [`Time#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) is an exact match to Python's, but you can still get `09:00 AM` with `some_time.strftime('%I:%M %p')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kristjan !. This is exactly what i was looking for :)